# Client config for private openvpn server

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, openvpn

I installed openvpn server on a local Ubuntu server at home. I want to use this to connect to in situations where I have to use public wifi. The server setup is done. I followed the Ubuntu guide, and that seemed to have worked. I've setup portforwarding on port 1194 UDP to the server. Now I need to get the client working. I'm on a Mac now, but I'll need this for Android as well, and possibly Ubuntu.

I can't seem to find a proper guide that tells me how to create a client config file. It should work with Tunnelblick, the OSX openvpn client, and I hope that will be enough to get Android working myself.

Do I need to create a client certificate on the server, or how does it work?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to create certificates for your clients on the server. The OpenVPN site offers a how-to here: http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#pki

Directly following the section about PKIs the how-to explains how to create server and client configs. It should provide all you need.

The how-to is rather involved but the basic idea is to setup a certificate authority for a public key infrastructure around your VPN service. Then you can create certificates for your clients and transfer the certificate files to your client. After that you create a config file for your VPN client. AFAIK, Tunnelblick offers a GUI to enter the appropriate data.

Comment: Thanks! I created the config files on the server, and then copied the files to the client. I renamed the folder to .tblk for tunnelblick, but now I get an error message related to tunnelblick. It cannot import the configuration it seems. Probably another question. I can try this on Android first.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. The last time I had to work with Tunnelblick it was a painful experience, too. You probably followed https://code.google.com/p/tunnelblick/wiki/cConfigT and considering the directions there, you need a valid .ovpn first. I'm not fond of the OpenVPN implementation on Android but I guess if it works there, you can be sure that at least the .ovpn is valid.